# Spring-roo 1.2.1 cannot filter the finder list?

Tags: spring-roo

the "finder list" command in Spring-roo, I added the "filter" parameter to cut down the list number of dynamic finder. But that didn't work for me, it listed the finders which contains "name" OR "price" for me.

```
 finder list --depth 2 --filter name,price
```

Can anyone tell me how to filter them for only contains "name" AND "price" finders?
i.e. 
findBooksByNameNotEqualsAndPrice(String name, Float price)
findBooksByNameEqualsAndPrice(String name, Float price)
......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Roo's source and it looks like there is no way to obtain the AND like behavior and only OR based logic is supported by the finder add-on.

See the finder addon src here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-roo/blob/master/addon-finder/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/addon/finder/FinderCommands.java#L71.

or the source code right here:

```
final SortedSet<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
for (final String finder : finders) {
    required: for (final String requiredEntry : requiredEntries) {
       if (finder.toLowerCase().contains(requiredEntry)) {
            result.add(finder);
            break required;
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

It looks like the list operation adds a filter to the result list every time it finds any required entry in the finder lower case name.

the only way I can think of to filter the list is to copy the output of the *finder list* command and run an external grep-like utility on it.
Otherwise you could try matching as much of the finders name as possible: something like *EqualsAndPrice(String name* for example. Ater all a plain java *String.contains* method is used.

Comment: Okay, that might be the only way. Hope roo will improve this command, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I have noticed that is easier to directly compound finder name in the annotation of your entity:
    @RooJpaActiveRecord(finders = { "findTubesByVectorOrResearcher","findTubesByBox" })
You can mix entity attributes, 'And', 'Or', 'Like', 'Between', etc.

For your question, I think grep is a straightforward solution.